# How to return a value in SSRS report when no data exists (test doesn't exist at that time)?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder, report-builder2.0

I have a filtered table (filtered by t1 and t3 values) with 6 columns (it has event number and t2 - t6 visible) in my SSRS report. I am using report builder.
I am having a problem because the t6 (Reason_Note) variable doesn't always have a value. And I don't mean it has a blank value. It appears as if that test does NOT EXIST.

For example: Over a timeframe, There are 5 rows of data that should appear in report. But for 2 of the 5, t6 has NO data (test doesn't exist), so the report only shows 3 rows. But I still want it to show all 5 rows it should, just leaving t6 blank. And I still want the t6 value to correspond to the correct rows (lined up with other columns). Is it possible to force t6 to be blank if the test doesn't exist?

I have tried IsNothing tests, but it doesn't work. It doesn't even recognize the test, so it seems like it doesn't even test for something/nothing.

Any help would be appreciated. Here is my current query:

```
 select e.event_num, event_status, e.event_ID, t1.result as Quality_issue, t2.result as 
 Reason, t3.result as Storage, t4.result as Grade, t5.result as Roll_Bulk, t6.result as 
 Reason_Note, prodstatus_desc_local P from events e
 left outer join tests t1 on (e.timestamp = t1.result_on)
 left outer join tests t2 on (e.timestamp = t2.result_on)
 left outer join tests t3 on (e.timestamp = t3.result_on)
 left outer join tests t4 on (e.timestamp = t4.result_on)
 left outer join tests t5 on (e.timestamp = t5.result_on)                                         
 left outer join tests t6 on (e.timestamp = t6.result_on)
 left outer join Production_status P on (e.Event_Status = P.ProdStatus_Id)
 Where (e.pu_id =2 and t1.var_id = 24777 and t2.var_id = 16 and t3.var_id = 312 and t4.var_id 
 = 1249 and t5.var_id = 1130 and t6.var_id = 3657 )
 and t1.result_on >=@StartTime
 and t1.result_on <@EndTime
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2NbU.png)

That is the data I get currently (Not sure if that picture worked). I would expect to have three more rows of data, but there is no value for t6 in those 3 rows, so it's not pulled in.
The only parameters are start time and end time.

[Source Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA4Pl.png)

Comment: Even though you are left joining to `t6` (which is OK) you still have t6 in your where clause so it will never return the row from events if t6 is null. Without seeing a sample of data I can't be certain but you should be able to update your where clause from `... and t6.var_id = 3657` to `... and (t6.var_id = 3657 or t6.var_id IS NULL)`

Comment: another thing to note, like Alan mentioned above, apart from checking for NULL, if you have any of your tables checking for conditions in your WHERE clause, it will changes all of your OUTER join into an INNER join. Since you have t1..t6 checking for var_id in your where clause, it will only ever return data where all 6 tests have value!

Comment: @AlanSchofield - Thank you for the reply. I tried your suggestion, but it still doesn't show the data. I believe that it is not considering the missing values null. The value for t6 is unavailable at that time, so it doesn't even "test" for null or not null. It's pulling data from a Plant Applications variable where the value is sometimes unavailable, not blank(null). I'm not very familiar with SQL language, so I'm not sure if this is even the best way to set this up. I just want to pull all the data within timeframe for these variables. And I can filter it in the filter tab. Thanks again.

Comment: Edit your question and provide some sample data from all the relevant tables and then show what you expect based on that data and I'm sure it will be easy to resolve. Also, explain what, if any, parameters are being passed to the dataset query from SSRS.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I added an image of the data I get. Let me know if that link didn't work. Thanks

Comment: We will need to see the data that is in your database tables (events, tests and production_status) or it will be difficult to find the problem with your query

Comment: @AlanSchofield Isn't that what the picture I posted is? Or did i misunderstand?

Comment: Thats just your results, we need to see your source data, some sample data from you database tables that you are querying.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I added a picture above. The data comes from Plant Applications, a program for manufacturing production info.

Comment: your query references 3 database tables/views (events, tests and production_status) , can you not just show some sample data from those?

Comment: @AlanSchofield That is all the data that is used. The event is the Roll ID at the top, the status is the row listed as status, and all the tests used are the rows with var IDs

Comment: OK, last time. I need to see data from each of the tables, I don't have time to try to reverse engineer them and build sample data. Please just show data from each of the 3 tables referenced in your query, show each table's data individually. Show the data as if you had just done `SELECT * FROM tests` for example. If you cannot do this then I cannot help.

Comment: @AlanSchofield The "Source Data" picture I posted is all of the data that I'm pulling from. All three of those come from the same place. Each column is an "Event." There is 1 status for each event listed on each column. And each test has a value for each specific event. I'm sorry, I must be misunderstanding you. I am new to the SQL language, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I don't mean to sound harsh but if you wrote the query, you must know that it references 3 database tables/views as signified by the following (from your query) `from events` ,  `join tests` and `join production_status`. The problem is with your query so unless I can see the data you are working with I can't help. The results of the query are not helpful as the query is wrong, it's the base data from the 3 tables/views I listed above that are required.

Comment: @AlanSchofield The data source is a PI Server. I can't exactly view that. It's not just a table that it's referencing.